# How can I upgrade my 10.04. to new version

Tags: 10.04, upgrade

I recently upgrade my ubuntu from 9.04 to 10.04 and when I open Update Manager, it says:

```
New Ubuntu release '12.04.1 LTS' is available.
```

*(Shouldn't it be 10.10 or 11.xx)?*

When I click 'upgrade', it fails with

```
Could not calculate the upgrade
```

How can I upgrade it to 12.04?

Comment: 10.10 is no longer supported, so the only upgrade path from 10.04 is 10.04->12.04. Try removing all third party (non-default) repositories and packages before upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

As said by mikewhatever above 10.10 is not supported anymore another reason is that when you upgrade to a Long Term Support release (LTS) like the 10.04 you get the option to upgrade straightaway to the next LTS release which is the 12.04.

For the problem about that the upgrade can't be calculated you need to remove added repositories. A thread at ubuntuforums is available that shows an example to this problem http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12236020#post12236020

Comment: What is 'added repositories'?

Comment: Upgrade-Manager shows...
----
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:
E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

This can be caused by :
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
-----------

How can I check what's wrong?

Comment: If you open update manager and then settings in the lower left. In the new window you have 5 tabs in the top. "Ubuntu Software", 
"Other Software", "Updates", "Authentication", "Statistics".

Open the "Other software" tab. Do you have any other sources checked than two "Independent"?

Comment: @RickGreen, who are you asking that question to? I'm still awaiting response from hytgbn if "added repositories" really is his/her problem, that's why it's a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try entering this into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It gives me "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."